# To show $f =0$ for the given integral $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The Q is : Suppose that $ f\geq 0$ and  $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = 0 $ Then prove that $f(x) = 0 \forall x \in [0,1]$

My solution : 
Assume $f(x) \neq 0  \forall x \in  [0,1] $ Let $g$ be another function continuous on $[0,1]$ such that $g(x) = 0 \forall x \in [0,1]$ now $g(x) < f(x) $ $ \forall x \in  [0,1] $
thus 
$$ \int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx < \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx  $$
$$ \Rightarrow 0 < \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx  $$ 
Contradiction thus  $f(x) \neq 0 \hspace{0.1in} \forall x \in  [0,1] $

Is this solution correct and rigorous ? Am I missing some important step ? 
Thanks

Comment: You want to argue by contradiction, but the negation of "$f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in [0, 1]$" is "$f(x)\neq 0$ for some $x\in [0,1]$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that your solution is correct. Your contradiction is not true.

Answer: Assume that $\exists x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, there exist a $\delta>0$ small enough such that $f(x)>\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$ for all $x\in (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$, (since
$$\varepsilon  = \frac{{f\left( {{x_0}} \right)}}{2} > 0,\,\,\exists \delta  > 0:\left| {x - {x_0}} \right| < \delta  \Rightarrow \left| {f\left( x \right) - f\left( {{x_0}} \right)} \right| < \frac{{f\left( {{x_0}} \right)}}{2}.)$$
Hence
$$\int_0^1 {f\left( x \right)dx}  \geqslant \int_{{x_0} - \delta }^{{x_0} + \delta } {f\left( x \right)dx}  \geqslant \int_{{x_0} - \delta }^{{x_0} + \delta } {\frac{{f\left( {{x_0}} \right)}}{2}dx}  = \frac{{f\left( {{x_0}} \right)}}{2}\int_{{x_0} - \delta }^{{x_0} + \delta } {dx}  = \delta f\left( {{x_0}} \right) > 0.$$
This is a contradiction. So $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

You should note that negation form of '$\forall x\in[0,1], f(x)=0$' is '$\exists x\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$'

So that, you can't go further in the step '$0=g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$'

I recommend you use $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$\Phi(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$
then by the fundamental theorem we have $\Phi'(x)=f(x)\ge0$ so $\Phi$ is increasing and since $\Phi(0)=\Phi(1)=0$ then $\Phi$ is constant on $[0,1]$ hence

$$f(x)=\Phi'(x)=0,\;\forall x\in[0,1]$$